# I'm trying to make a simple salary counting program. But i cant recieve the data from the other class to the main activity

Tags: android

This is my main activity. im new to android. i know some basics of java now. But in the onclick listener i cant manupulate the data.

```
package com.examp.emp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Employee emp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText ed =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText ed1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText ed2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int sa =Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
                int da=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());

                emp.salary=sa;
                emp.day=da;

                double tot=emp.compute();
                ed2.setText(""+tot);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

CLASS:

```
public class Employee extends MainActivity {

    double salary;
    int day;

    public double compute(){
        double fine = (salary/30)*day;
        double total=salary-fine;
        return total;
    }
}
```

enter code here
This are my errors in log cat:

```
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926): Process: com.examp.emp, PID: 926
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.examp.emp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-28 02:57:00.616: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 03:02:01.006: I/Process(926): Sending signal. PID: 926 SIG: 9
```

Please help me.I will be so greatfull....`

Comment: what is there are line at com.examp.emp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33). It seems text from Edit Text is null

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee is never initialized

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` class is just declared not initialized. So initialize it on `onCreate()` method.

```
emp = new Employee();
```

Comment: @ShifinRafeeq Your wel come. Glad to help you